# Why does this audio clip not play while reseting the scene in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LogicScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int score;
    public Text scoreText;
    public GameObject GameOverScreen;



    [ContextMenu ("add score")]
    public void addScore(int scoreToAdd)
    { 
        score += scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString() +" Majors";
    }
    public void restartGame()
    {
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        CanI();
         
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        GameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public AudioSource src;
    public AudioClip sfx, sfx2, sfx3, sfx4; 

    public void weMajor()
    {
        src.clip = sfx;
        src.Play();
    }

    public void End()
    {
        src.clip = sfx2;
        src.Play();
    }
    public void CanI()
    {
        src.clip = sfx3;
        src.Play();
    }

    public void Intro()
    {
        src.clip = sfx4;
        src.Play();
    }

}
```

Im calling the restartGame() function using a button, but the CanI() function never plays any audio. I know both the button and the CanI() function work independently but for some reason not when combining them like this. In my mind the scene should reset, the audio should play and then the computer exits the function. Why dosent this happen, what am i supposed to do?

Comment: probably because this game object is destroyed as the scene is told to load

Answer (score 0):

the `CanI()` function comes after the loadScene, so it will not be called.

Try this:

```
public void restartGame()
{
    CanI();
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

Comment: why should it not be called? c# doesn't just stop mid-method ;)

Comment: @derHugo,  lol it's been a long time didn't use it forgot everything

Answer (score 0):

with `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` unity destroy your LogicScript and create new one. as you didn't add any `Awake` or `Start` method to call when new object instantiated the audio clip won't play.
i suggest to seprate your Audio and your logic into two different scripts.
create an singleton script called AudioManager and add DontDestroyOnLoad:

```
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

attach this script to an object in your first scene so this script never destroy on loading scene.